# Why my Ratcher Server on Laravel is not working?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, ratchet

When I try to connect with my Ratchet Server on Laravel Firefox say " cannot connect with server ws://localhost:8080/."

I used askedio/laravel-ratchet package

There is my config:

```
     'class'           => App\RatchetServer::class,
'host'            => '0.0.0.0', // Prepend tls:// to host address to enable SSL/TLS. Example: tls://0.0.0.0
'port'            => '8080',
'connectionLimit' => false,
'throttle'        => [
    'onOpen'    => '5:1',
    'onMessage' => '20:1',
 ],
'abortOnMessageThrottle' => false,
'blackList'              => [],
'zmq'                    => [
    'host'   => '127.0.0.1',
    'port'   => 5555,
    'method' => \ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL,
],
/**
 * Look up http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php to configure SSL/TLS.
 */
'tls'             => [
    // 'peer_name' => '',
    // 'verify_peer' => true,
    // 'verify_peer_name' => true,
    // 'allow_self_signed' => false,
    'cafile' => env('SSL_CA_FILE', ''),
    'capath' => env('SSL_CA_PATH', ''),
    'local_cert' => env('SSL_PUBLIC_CERT', ''),
    'local_pk' => env('SSL_PRIVATE_KEY', ''),
    'passphrase' => env('SSL_PASSPHRASE', ''),
],
```

Comment: add command which you are using to serve application

Comment: I'm not serving it on my pc, I upload laravel project to server.

Comment: Set host to 127.0.0.1, check nothing else throttling port 8080. 0.0.0.0 is not localhost. [The address 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non-applicable target.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)